# Is the norm square of a ReLU function differentiable?

Tags: matrix-calculus, subgradient

Suppose $f(X)$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(X)=\lVert\sigma(X)\rVert_F^2$, where $\sigma(X)=\max\{X,0\}$ is an entry-wise ReLU function, i.e., mapping each entry $x_{ij}$ of the matrix $X$ to $\max\{x_{ij},0\}$. How can we determine whether $f(X)$ is a differentiable function with respect to $X$ and if it is differentiable, how to calculate its derivative? or if not differentiable, how to calculate its sub-gradient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\r{\operatorname{\sigma}}
\def\s{\operatorname{sign}}
\def\t{\operatorname{trace}}
$Given the scalar `sign()` function
$$\eqalign{
\s(\lambda) = \begin{cases}
+\o\quad{\rm if}\;\lambda\ge 0 \\
-\o\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
}$$
the element-wise `sign()` function and the *all-ones* matrix $(J)$ can be used to write an equivalent expression for the element-wise `ReLu()` function
$$\eqalign{
S &= \s(X), \qquad
\r(X) &= \frac 12\big(S+J\big) \\
}$$
Use these results to analyze your function
$$\eqalign{
f &= \t(\sigma^T\sigma) \\
  &= \frac 14\t(S^TS) + \frac 12\t(J^TS) + \frac 14\t(J^TJ) \\
df &= \frac 12\t\!\Big((S+J)^TdS\Big) \\
}$$
So that's the sub-differential of your $f$ function in terms of
the sub-differential of the `sign()` function.

The `sign()` function is not differentiable at $\lambda=0\,$ and elsewhere its derivative equals zero.

Comment: so the origin function is actually differentiable, and the derivative is not differentiable, right?